# Suppose $Q$ is p.s.d and $P$ is p.d. on the nullspace of $Q$, then $\exists c > 0$ such that $P+cQ$ is p.d.

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, optimization

**Motivation:** The following lemma, which is used in a proof in Optimization (sufficient conditions for minima using Lagrange multipliers)

> Suppose $P, Q$ are symmetric matrices, and $Q$ is p.s.d. Furthermore, for all $x \in \text{Null}(Q)$ (except $0$), we have $x^TPx > 0$. Then there exists a $c>0$ such that $\forall x: x^T(P+cQ)x > 0$.

My book does contain a proof (which I present below), but I am wondering if there are any others. In particular, I think there should be a proof along the following lines, but I haven't come up with one: Develop some sharp lower bounds on $x^T P x$ and $x^TQx$. Then we can have $x^TPx + cx^TQx \ge f(c, x)$, and hopefully  it will be clear that for large enough $c$, we have $\forall x f(c, x) > 0$.

**Proof presented in the book:** Assume the contrary. Then there is a sequence $(x_k)$ with $||x_k|| = 1$ such that $x_k^T(P+kQ)x_k \le 0$. Being on a compact space, this sequence has a subsequence converging to some $x^*$. After a little manipulation, we arrive at ${x^*}^TQx^* = 0$ (which implies $Qx^* = 0)$ while ${x^*}^TPx^* \le 0$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Of course you mean "for all $x \in \text{Null}(Q)$ except $0$".

Comment: The compactness of the unit sphere is likely to play a role somehow in any proof, because the result is not true for hermitian operators on an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Yes sorry forgot about $x = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $p=\min\{x^TPx:\|x\|=1,x\in\ker(Q)\}$ and $q=\min\{x^TQx:\|x\|=1,x\in\ker(Q)^\perp\}$. By the given conditions, both $p$ and $q$ are positive. For any vector $v$, let $v=x+y$ where $x\in\ker(Q)$ and $y\in\ker(Q)^\perp$. Then
\begin{aligned}
v^T(P+cQ)v
&=x^TPx+2x^TPy+y^TPy+cy^TQy\\
&\ge p\|x\|^2-2\|P\|\|x\|\|y\|-\|P\|\|y\|^2+cq\|y\|^2\\
&=p\|x\|^2-2\|P\|\|x\|\|y\|+(cq-\|P\|)\|y\|^2.
\end{aligned}
The expression on last line is a quadratic polynomial in $\|x\|$ and $\|y\|$ and whose discriminant is $\|P\|^2-p(cq-\|P\|)$. One can pick any $c$ such that $cq-\|P\|$ is positive and the discrimant is negative.